# Use Group By for real or float column with specify precision

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How can I specify precision for a column of the ***REAL*** type (eg. to three digits after the decimal point) for *Group By* clause?

Eg. 12.023006 is equal to 12.023007 for 3 digits precision after the decimal point and should be grouped by *Group By*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple ways you can achieve this, one of which is to `CAST` your field to the appropriate precision:

```
select cast(somecol as decimal(10,3))
from sometable
group by cast(somecol as decimal(10,3))
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7958d/1)

You could also use the `ROUND` function to achieve this.